# Dialogflow issue in extracting entities with similar items

Tags: nlp, entity, dialogflow-es

I have created a user-defined/custom entity as synonyms with below items, but dialogflow having an issue to identify the entity with similar names but only a character different at last.

```
'STM32L151V8H6' 
'STM32L151V8H6A'    
'STM32L151V8T6' 
'STM32L151V8T6A'    
'STM32L151VBH6' 
'STM32L151VBH6A'    
'STM32L151VBT6' 
'STM32L151VBT6A'
```

So it is extracted STM32L151VBT6A in place of STM32L151VBT6.

Please advise on how to solve this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enable **Fuzzy Matching**: [Check docs for more info](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-fuzzy)

[image]

Or you can use **Regexp entities**: [check docs for more info](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/entities-regexp)

> Some entities need to match patterns rather than specific terms. For example, national identification numbers, IDs, license plates, and so on. With **regexp** entities, you can provide regular expressions for matching.

**UPDATE**

In reply to your comment, you can get the original (what the user actually said) entity detected using **$EntityName.original** (check below example image)

[image]

But for your use case i advise against doing that using synonyms, if there is a common pattern you should definitely use **RegEx**

Comment: Sorry I'm looking for an exact match, but it is showing an approximate match

Comment: What do you mean it is showing an approximate match ? if you want to match an exact expected pattern, you can use Regexp

Comment: I don't want a pattern match, but I want to extract the exact synonyms such as if user enters STM32L151VBH6 it is showing as STM32L151VBH6A, but it need to be STM32L151VBH6